# XCode Code Coverage - how to display information for functions not covered

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, code-coverage

What would be a wise choice in displaying/deriving data for functions that aren't covered by unit tests within a project? I think it would be useful to have this data to pinpoint opportunities to increase code coverage within a project. I am using Xcode 7.2 and Swift.

Comment: I don't understand the question, do you want to be able to see code coverage for each file?

Comment: So you know how there is a list for each class for functions you've covered? I would like to do the opposite and display a list for functions that aren't covered.

Comment: Functions that aren't covered just show no blue bar don't they? You can sort by coverage percentage at the top using the table header.